# how do I delete records PouchDB completly?

Tags: indexeddb, pouchdb

I am creating a PouchDb like so :
`var db = new PouchDB('my_db',{ auto_compaction: true, revs_limit: 1 });`

then i insert and delete the documents using bulkDocs methods, But i could not delete the document completely still the documents rev id exist in the database:

```
{_deleted: true, _doc_id_rev: "1a458e09-4f5b-493a-ac15-1c370643efb4::2-4d710a8434ba561cb0ba057f9b9ec6c3"}
```

How do i remove that.

Comment: See the newish 'purge' method https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/pull/8453

Comment: @RamblinRose, thanks for your reply,  i am using pouchDb in browsers alone, if i use purge its throw error - purge is not implemented for this adapter

Comment: In that case an alternative is to replicate documents from one db to another, filtering away the deleted documents, then swapping the definitive db. This increases complexity greatly if sync to a remote db is required however.